# what is the significance of pilot carriers in ofdm

Tags: fft, digital-communications

in an OFDM system having a radix two FFT (Say N=64) . all of these sub-carriers are not utilized. while some of the carriers are nulls to prevent leakage in to adjacent bands, say a four to five carriers will be pilots. and the remaining will be the data carriers. what is the significance of pilot carriers in OFDM system

regards,
phani tej

Answer (score 0):

OFDM pilot symbols are used to measure channel conditions and/or obtain synchronization information.